# WPF RelativeSource binding question

Tags: wpf, binding, relativesource

HI!
I have an Expander and a TextBox.
I want to disable the TextBox when the Expander is expanded and enable when it's not expanded.
How to do that? I've tried something like this:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Expander}, AncestorLevel=1},Path=IsExpanded}" />
```

But it's vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the AncestorLevel property, it's error prone and usually not necessary